# I want to set a url inside my ajax call back function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I want to make a clickable link in my ajax success response. But I could not do this.

```
<td id="attachment"></td>
```

---

```
function DoAction(id) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "/view_message",
    data: "id=" + id,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      if (data) {
        var text = "No Files There !";
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
        $('#subject').text(data.subject);
        $('#body').text(data.body);
        $('#created_at').text(data.created_at);
        if (data.attachment) {

          $('#attachment').html('<a href="files/' + data.attachment + '" />click</a>');

        } else {
          $('#attachment').text(text);
        }
      }
    }
  });
}
```

I want to display a clickable link in my .

Comment: What's the matter with the code you have? Is it throwing an error? Is it just not working, and if so, how is it not working?

Comment: what is the response of `url: "/view_message",`?

Comment: Show your success `data` variable

Answer (score 1):

I always encounter this when using ajax calls so;

Update your code from this.

```
$('#attachment').html('<a href="files/' + data.attachment + '" />click</a>');
```

To This.

```
$(document).find('#attachment').html('<a href="files/' + data.attachment + '" />click</a>');
```

if the code doesn't work add a `console.log("working")` function to see if your code is really reaching the success function.

I hope it helps.